# Jquery post json data and interpreting with spring at serverside

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I am about to write an application where I have to send `JSON` data using `jQuery` post and interpret the same in spring controller at the server side. I am facing so many issues in interpreting the data at the server side even after so many trails and errors. I have gone through so many posts in `stackoverflow` also but not able to found the right answer.

Is posting the data in `JSON` format to spring is preferred or not ? pls let me know.

Even if you post a link explaining how to handle the data at the server side it would be helpful.

Comment: JSON makes passed data universal, visual and simple to use ... JSON is a good choice.

Comment: do you want to me to post the code with which i am trying for past two days ?

Comment: What's is your server's JSON handling code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a good format for passing data back and forth between client and server. Look into deserialization to get your *well-formed* JSON into an object(s) on the server.

Comment: Any links for the above where it is implemented as example will help me better..thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+mvc+deserlization+json&oq=spring+mvc+deserlization+json&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&spell=1&q=spring+mvc+deserialization+json&sa=X&ei=gcuDUOSaFO-r0AHd6oDgDA&ved=0CB4QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1280&bih=622

Comment: You should find a few in that internet query.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what data you are going to pass from client to server. But yes, JSON is good enough format for general data and i prefer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sure from your answer what type of problem you are facing. Supposing that your main problem is to post json data from jquery/any other source and interpreting it, the solution is as follows :

1. Create a model object that implements Serializable interface. e.g.

   public class Account implements Serializable{

   ```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1913207428686438208L;
    String bankAccountNo ;
    String userName ;

   public String getBankAccountNo() {
       return bankAccountNo;
   }

   public void setBankAccountNo(String bankAccountNo) {
       this.bankAccountNo = bankAccountNo;
   }

   public String getUserName() {
       return userName;
   }

   public void setUserName(String userName) {
       this.userName = userName;
   }

   public void Account(){

   }
   ```

   }

2.Annotate your controller with request mapping path, e.g

```
@Controller("jsonController")
@RequestMapping("test/")
public class JSONController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "get/account/{name}", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Account getAccount(@PathVariable String name) {
        // let's suppose findAccount() finds the account
        Account account = findAccount(name);
        return account;
    }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "post/account", headers = "Content-type=application/json")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getAccount(@PathVariable String name) {
        // let's suppose saveAccount() persists the account
        saveAccount(account);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

1. add jackson-mapper-asl.jar and jackson-core-asl.jar to library.
2. add `<context:annotation-config/>` to your applicationContext.xml file.

hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying with the given code...let me check and will update you. thank you.

Comment: Added the javascript and context file below. Pls check and let me know if any thing wrong the way i am posting the data.

Comment: javascript and context file seem ok, what is the problem now? what's the result after posting the data?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am adding missing components from my end ....Pls correct it if any thing is wrong with below code: 
Context xml file:

```
    <mvc:resources location="/custom1/" mapping="/js/**" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vk" />
    <context:annotation-config />    
    <bean id="JspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />     
</bean>
```

and javascript code below:

```
   $.ajax({url: "/JSONExample/post/account",
        type: "POST",
        data: {userName: "Sam" },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
               }
        });
```